# The size of the sample for split validation

Tags: data-mining, cross-validation, dataset, validation

At this moment I have a dataset with 4000 samples (50% positive and 50% negative). Normally I would do cross validation for this approach, however besides normal data mining techniques I am  also trying an alternate ILP  approach.

Since I can't implement cross validation using the ILP system I am using, to maintain dataset coherence between the two types of techniques I decided to instead do a split validation. I keep hearing about split validation should only be used in large datasets, but how large should they be? Would implement it on this one produce unacceptable  "bad" results? Should I really avoid this approach?

Comment: It's unclear which "ILP" you are using.  Otherwise, you are asking largely for opinions about what you should do and about what is good or bad.  This site is better suited to questions about how things work or about what the truth of a matter is.

Comment: I am using the Aleph system. And I am asking how split validation would work work in this situation, so I think it's on the scope of this site.

Comment: Please explain in a short sentence your http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILP. I don't see why you cannot do resampling validation.

Comment: ILP here stands for Inductive Logic Programming.

Answer (score 4):

Can you explain *why* you cannot do resampling validation?:

- All you really need for resampling validation is a method to get predictions for unknown cases.
- And you can certainly also apply the very same splits to more than one classification algorithm in order to get paired data for a comparison.

Comment: Ah, the answer _I_ was looking for :)

Comment: Because I am using rapidminer, and I can't see how exactly he splitting the data for cross validatio, whereas I can recreate the split validation for the Aleph dataset.

Comment: But you could write a script that does the splitting on your desktop and then push(es) training data and unknown test cases to rapidminer, right? I mean, doing a single iteration/repetition of a 4-fold cross validation isn't *that* much hassle, is it? And it gives you so much more information (at least if you can get the model out of Rapidminer).